# Is there a way to force specific dataTable columns to show on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, datatables, responsive

I'm currently using DataTables which works very well for larger viewports, but I'm struggling to force the tables to show the first and third columns of each table when visiting the site from a mobile.

[Image: Only the first column is visible, but I'd like to show the third column next to the first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO9eT.png)

I've tried using the 'responsivePriority' option for columns and the '.all' class in an attempt to force the third column to show next to the first, but unfortunately these did not work for me.

Is there another way I could force the third column to show next to first column when viewing the table from a mobile/small viewport?

Comment: Did you look at this? https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Comment: Yes, I had a look at the columns.visible() options as well, although I don't see how that can help in this case since the default = true. I'm not trying to hide a column, I'm trying to make another show for mobile/smaller viewport; although, I can't find a way to force a second column to show. (as seen in the image attached)

Comment: You could use an alternative column configuration for mobile, where you can change the order or visibility of columns.

Comment: Visibility for all columns are set to 'true', but even so, I can't get a second column to show when visiting the site from mobile. I tried all the possible fixes mentioned in the question, but those don't seem to work. I always end up with only one column showing (like the attached image)